# Focus a focused input on clicking other div without triggering blur?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div container with input text-field. I attached an focus-in and focus-out animation on this input's focus/blur event listeners. However, I want the input to behave in a way such that when I click anywhere on this div container, it is the same as focusing on that input itself (thus will not refocus if input is already focused).

[This should illustrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/g5c7d/2/)

```
    $("#foo1").click(function() {
       //WARNING: #foo2 will blur first THEN focus 
       $("#foo2").focus();
    });

    $("#foo2").focus(function() {
        $("#foo1").addClass("active",1000);
    });
    $("#foo2").blur(function() {
        $("#foo1").removeClass("active",1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't re-apply the animation if its already .active

```
$(function(){
    $("#foo1").click(function() {
        //WARNING: #foo2 will blur first THEN focus 
        $("#foo2").focus();
    });

    $("#foo2").focus(function() {
        //dont reapply
        $("#foo1:not(.active)").addClass("active",1000);
    });
    $("#foo2").blur(function() {
        $("#foo1").removeClass("active",1000);
    });

});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/g5c7d/6/

Comment: It works, but in case there are multiple classes change per focus, then I will have to readjust selector accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to update the code if you change your requirements but  `$("#foo1:not(.active)").addClass("active ohAndAnotherClass",1000);` is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

use [.clearQueue()](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

> When the .clearQueue() method is called, all functions on the queue
>   that have not been executed are removed from the queue.

**js**

```
$(function(){
    $("#foo1").click(function() {
        //WARNING: #foo2 will blur first THEN focus 
        $("#foo2").focus();
    });

        $("#foo2").focus(function() {
            $("#foo1").clearQueue().addClass("active",1000);
        });
        $("#foo2").blur(function() {
            $("#foo1").clearQueue().removeClass("active",1000);
        });


});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5c7d/3/)

Comment: Is the queue shared between elements? What if there are other completely irrelevant delay functions being queued, will foo1.clearQueue clear those functions?

Comment: @user1542639 yes clearQueue  will clear all the previous functions

Comment: Your answer works fine, but I would have to go with the other answer. I am quite hesitated to do a clearQueue, because it might unintentionally erase other irrelevant delay functions.